# MySQL GROUP BY on SELECT If Statement

Tags: mysql

I'm am trying to join a table that has a boolean column, and in my results I'm trying to get two columns from the join, one where the boolean is 0 and a separate on where it is 1.

Since there is a one to many relationship, I need to do a GROUP BY.

The following query returns the correct non GROUP BY results.

For each profile ID there is at least one row for both genre and influence.

```
SELECT p.profileID, IF( gpro.isInfluence =0, g.genreName, NULL ) AS genre, IF( gpro.isInfluence =1, g.genreName, NULL ) AS influence, g.genreName
FROM profiles p
LEFT JOIN genre_profiles gpro ON gpro.profileID = p.profileID
LEFT JOIN genres g ON g.genreID = gpro.genreID
WHERE g.genreName IS NOT NULL
```

However, when I do the corresponding GROUP BY/GROUP_CONCAT the output does not make sense.

```
SELECT p.profileID, IF( gpro.isInfluence =0, GROUP_CONCAT( g.genreName ) , NULL ) AS genre, IF( gpro.isInfluence =1, GROUP_CONCAT( g.genreName ) , NULL ) AS influence, g.genreName
FROM profiles p
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre_profiles gpro ON gpro.profileID = p.profileID
LEFT OUTER JOIN genres g ON g.genreID = gpro.genreID
WHERE g.genreName IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.profileID
```

The above groups all the g.genreName rows in either of the columns, instead of them being split based on the gpro.isInfluence value. The column the result falls under I believe corresponds to the first result that is grouped.

```
1000001052  Latin American,Rock,Hip Hop NULL
1000001637  NULL    Electronic,Easy listening,Asian,popgun
1000001666  NULL    Electronic,Bacon,Emo,Modern folk,Hip Hop,R...
```

What I don't understand is why are the genre values are grouped together and not in their respective columns like the first query.

Comment: You'd do well to supply your table structure and, if possible, a SQLFiddle ( http://sqlfiddle.com/ )

Comment: Maybe you used group_concat in a wrong way

Comment: I'll make a couple fiddles.  I left out the full structure so it wouldn't get too complicated.

Comment: "Maybe you used group_concat in a wrong way" BINGO!

If you put the GROUP_CONCAT on the outside of the IF statement it works as intended.

Comment: @bikedorkseattle please upvote comment :) You stole the answer anyway :)

Comment: @Ertunç I did brother :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.profileID, GROUP_CONCAT( IF( gpro.isInfluence =0, g.genreName, NULL ) ) AS genre, GROUP_CONCAT( IF( gpro.isInfluence =1, g.genreName, NULL ) ) AS influence, g.genreName
FROM profiles p
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre_profiles gpro ON gpro.profileID = p.profileID
LEFT OUTER JOIN genres g ON g.genreID = gpro.genreID
WHERE g.genreName IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p.profileID
```

Putting the GROUP_CONCAT outside the IF statement gives the correct output, thanks to Ertunc for helping my brain make the pivot on that one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic statement to apply **IF** condition in **Select** statement with `GROUP BY` clause.

```
GROUP_CONCAT( IF (condition, 1, 0)) col
```

As GROUP_CONCAT return multiple `,` separated values. With the below line of statement we can avoid duplicate values

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF (condition, 1, 0)) col
```